# Measuring PC Use

Tags: windows, windows-10

We have a small workspace with three domain-joined PCs (currently Windows 10 x64 1809) where anyone in the organization can sit down, log in with their AD credentials, and use them for a while if they need to.

I need to know how often these stations are actually used.

How can I get this data?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be more appropriate within the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.

Comment: Many domain management tools also offer this sort of reporting, but Window's built in reporting does this just fine too.

Comment: For a whole domain, I might have asked on ServerFault. But for three machines? That opens up a whole set of options server people wouldn't think of.

Comment: Possibly so, but those three machines **are** on a domain.  As an IT manager whose employees maintain several different Windows domains, I can safely say that they have a thorough understanding of both Windows 10 workstation configurations and domain auditing policies.  The community at Server Fault has a similar set of expertise.  In contrast, while some people within the Super User realm also support corporate domains, most of them probably don't.  As a result, you are much more likely to only get "half the story" at Super User, while the Server Fault crew *does* manage domain computers.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable tracking of logon and logoff [following this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/556015) by adding a script to run at logon, and another script to run at logoff. This requires enabling Auditing on the domain level by using Group Policy.

Comment: But is this already recorded somewhere, or will I need to wait six months after turning it on to be able to produce a reasonable graph over time? Even it it means manually mining Windows Event logs, I could turn open WIM ports to allow remove event viewer connections to those machines and do this now from my desk.

Comment: Perhaps there's a software product you could ask for on http://softwarecs.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.stackexchange.com to comb through the Security logs for logon and logoff events. Might even be one that's Open Source.